# Django database to html

Tags: django

I’m having a little troubles . I’m trying to show an object from my database to my html webpage
I have it set up as:

```
def index(request):
    quotes = Quote.objects.all()[:1]
```

*** I imported the model, and also I’m using one because I only want that current one]

```
render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {"quote": quote})
```

I then use the for loop in my index template but it will not show up, 
I use

```
{% block content %}
{% for data in quote %}
<h2>{{data.body}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

but I can use {{quote}} by itself and get the object in the database. To show any help getting the actual body text? I get no errors. Nothing shows.  in my models.py ;I have body with text field. I have

```
 class Quote(models.Model):
   body = models.TextField()
    def __str__():
       return self.body
```

I just want to display the quote I have in my data base. When I go to localhost:8000/admin. I can insert the quote. I go to phpmyadmin, I see the quote. I even see it when I call the object. I just can’t display it inside html . Help please!

**p.s I typed this question on my cellular device **

Comment: I assume it's just a transcription error that you call the variable `quotes` to start and then `quote` afterwards?

Comment: My intuition here is that somehow `quote` is just a single `Quote` instance, rather than a list.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with typing things on your mobile - I do it all the time - but it means that this is not your actual code. What you have posted would not produce the problem that you see, so you really need to show the code that you are actually running.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `Quote.objects.first()` which will return one instance or `None`.

Example would be:

```
def index(request):
    quote = Quote.objects.first()
    render(request, homepage/index.html, {“quote”: quote})
```

And then:

```
{%block content%}
<h2>{{quote.body}}</h2>
{%endblock%}
```

Give that a try!

Comment: Thanks for the reply !

Comment: This should work, so please share more of you code. There must be something else that is not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def index(request):
    quotes = Quote.objects.all()[:1]
    context = dict()
    context['quotes'] = quotes
    render(request, 'homepage/index.html', context)
```

Now add the below code in your template

```
{% block content %}
      {% for quote in quotes %}
          <h2>{{quote.body}}</h2>
      {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It didn’t work :/ it’s not displaying the quote on my webpage

Comment: Can you check if "<h2></h2>" exists in your HTML code? This means that there's something wrong in the backend. Also, can you run the debugger in Django and check what is the value "quotes" before rendering the page.